# How a MOSFET transistor works [deeply]?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I want to know deeply about how a MOSFET transistor works ! for example , Why electric field makes electron flowing ? , Why do we use metal oxide instead of other materials ? , what is advantages for using MOSFET instead of normal transistor ? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You just asked a question requiring many years of training and reading to answer. This site will not be able to provide you with a sufficient answer.

Comment: You should try google or a physics site for this.

Comment: 'How it works' and 'what are advantages of using instead of normal transistors' are two *very* different questions. And BTW, physics doesn't answer 'why' questions, 'why electric field makes electron flowing'. Nobody knows why, we just know it does. Physics can help with how fast it flows, when it flows, what the flow does, how to control the flow, but not why. Actually, that why and the metal oxide question makes 4 very different questions. VTC for far far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not expect a deep answer in StackExchange. It is a platform for short and clear answers for specific questions. I assume that you ask for sources to look at and learn from them.

Tsividis has a very detailed book about it. Almost 1000 pages if I am right. This is the deepest source I can think of. He also had a Coursera lecture few years ago.

Otherwise just go into the library of the nearest technical university and ask for textbooks for microelectronics. This might suit you better.